# How can i split my function into two separate functions?

Tags: php, mysql

When someone registers on my site, there's currently no message that the email is taken. It only throws an error if a username taken. I would like to split my usernameExists function in two pieces, but still being able to log in using username or email. I tried spliting it on my own but with no success.

start of functions.inc.php file

```
<?php

function emptyInputSignup($username, $email, $pwd, $pwdRepeat ){
    $result;
    if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($pwd) || empty($pwdRepeat)){
        $result = true;
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

function checkboxChecked($checkbox){
    $result;
    if (empty($checkbox)){
        $result = true; 
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

function invalidUsername($username){
    $result;
    if (!preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%^&_-]{3,16}$/',$username)){
        $result = true;
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

function invalidPassword($pwd){
    $result;
    if (!preg_match("/^(?=.*[!@#$%^&])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])[!@#$%^&*a-zA-Z0-9]{8,24}$/", $pwd)){
        $result = true;
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

function invalidEmail($email){
    $result;
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $result = true;
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

function pwdMatch($pwd, $pwdRepeat){
    $result;
    if ($pwd !== $pwdRepeat){
        $result = true;
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

function usernameExists($conn, $username, $email){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= ? OR userEmail = ?;";
    $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
    }

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $email);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $resultData=mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    if($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)){
      return $row;
    }
    else{
        $result=false;
        return $result;
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

function createUser($conn, $username, $email, $pwd){
    $sql="INSERT INTO users (username, userEmail, userPwd) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
    $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=stmtfailed");
        exit();
    }

    $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $email, $hashedPwd);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    header("location: ../signup.php?error=none");
    exit();
}

function emptyInputLogin($username, $pwd){
    $result;
    if (empty($username) || empty($pwd)){
        $result = true;
    }
    else{
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

function loginUser($conn, $username, $pwd){
    $usernameExists = usernameExists($conn, $username, $username);

    if($usernameExists===false){
    header("location: ../login.php?error=wronglogin");
    exit();
    }

    $pwdHashed = $usernameExists["userPwd"];
    $checkPwd = password_verify($pwd, $pwdHashed);

    if($checkPwd===false){
    header("location: ../login.php?error=wrongpassword");
    exit();
    }
    else if($checkPwd === true){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["userid"] = $usernameExists["userId"];
        $_SESSION["userName"] = $usernameExists["username"];
        header("location: ../index.php");
        exit();
    }

}
```

end of functions.inc.php file

start of signup.inc.php file

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $username=$_POST["username"];
    $email=$_POST["email"];
    $pwd=$_POST["pwd"];
    $pwdRepeat=$_POST["pwdrepeat"];
    $checkbox=$_POST["chkbx"];

    require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
    require_once 'functions.inc.php';

    if (emptyInputSignup($username, $email, $pwd, $pwdRepeat )!==false){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=emptyinput");
        exit();
    }
    if (invalidUsername($username)!==false){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=invalidUsername");
        exit();
    }
  
    if (invalidPassword($pwd)!==false){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=invalidPassword");
        exit();
    }
  
    if (invalidEmail($email)!==false){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=invalidEmail");
        exit();
    }
    if (pwdMatch($pwd, $pwdRepeat)!==false){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=passwordsdontmatch");
        exit();
    }
    if (usernameExists($conn, $username, $email)!==false){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=usernametaken");
        exit();
    }
    
    if (checkboxChecked($checkbox)!==false){
        header("location: ../signup.php?error=checkboxnotchecked");
        exit();
    }


    createUser($conn, $username, $email, $pwd);
}
else{
    header("location: ../signup.php");
    $_POST["name"];
}
```

end of signup.inc.php file

start of signup.php file

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<?php
    include_once 'head.php';
?>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signup.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="button_shine.css">
    <title>StatTracker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        include_once 'navbar.php';
    ?>



        <div class="content">
            <h1>Sign up to <span style="color:#41d740">XXXXXXXXXr</span>XXXXXX</h1>
            <h3>XXXXXXX<b>XXXXX</b>XXXXXXXX</h3>
            <div class="window">
                <div class="sign_up_inputs">

                    <form action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="POST">
                    <img src="img/user.png"><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username (3-16 characters)"><br>
                    <img src="img/mail.png"><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"><br>
                    <img src="img/lock.png"><input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password"><br>
                    <img src="img/lock.png"><input type="password" name="pwdrepeat" placeholder="Repeat password"><br>
                </div>

                <div class="sign_up_rest">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="chkbx">
                    <p>I have read and accepted the terms of the privacy policy, license agreement etc.</p><br>
                    <div class="submit"></div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" id="submit"><br>
                </form>

                    <?php
                        echo "
                        <div class='alreadyhave'>
                            <a>Already have an account? <a href='signup.php' style='color:#41d740; font-weight: bold;text-decoration:none;'>Sign Up!</a></a>
                        </div>";

                        echo "<div class='error_handlers'>";

                        if(isset($_GET["error"])){
                            if($_GET["error"]=="emptyinput"){
                                echo "<p>Fill in all fields!</p>";
                            }
                            else if($_GET["error"]=="invalidUsername"){
                                echo "<p>Invalid username!</p>";
                            }
                            else if($_GET["error"]=="invalidemail"){
                                echo "<p>Invalid Email!</p>";
                            }
                            else if($_GET["error"]=="passwordsdontmatch"){
                                echo "<p>Passwords doesn't match!</p>";
                            }
                            else if($_GET["error"]=="invalidPassword"){
                                echo "<p>Password doesn't meet requierments</p>";
                            }
                            else if($_GET["error"]=="stmtfailed"){
                                echo "<p>Oops! Something went wrong, try again!</p>";
                            }
                            else if($_GET["error"]=="usernametaken"){
                                echo "<p>Username already taken!</p>";
                            }
                            else if($_GET["error"]=="checkboxnotchecked"){
                                echo "<p>Checkbox not checked!</p>";
                            }
                            else if($_GET["error"]=="none"){
                                echo "<p style='color:green'>You have signed up!</p>";
                                header("Refresh: 1; url=login.php");
                                exit();
                            }
                        }

                        
                        echo "</div>";
                    ?>

                </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        




<?php
    include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

end of signup.php file

Im not very experienced php coder so my previous tries would not help, but I just want it to work the way i described it before.

On signup.php I want to have a message that username is taken and email is taken, both separately.

Comment: Are you watching Dani Krossing's tutorial on YouTube? Please stop. This is an awful tutorial and you are doing yourself a huge disservice. Please pick a modern tutorial that uses PDO.

Comment: Ok, I'll have it in mind. Do you recommend any good tutorialist?

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection. Here are some good video tutorials https://youtu.be/2eebptXfEvw & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVbEyFZKgqk&list=PLr3d3QYzkw2xabQRUpcZ_IBk9W50M9pe-

Comment: I appreciate a lot man, I'll check it right now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).